# X command not working to redirect output to file

Tags: sas

When I am submitting the following lines in **cmd** ,it returns the expected output by making a csv file.

```
C:\>Tasklist /FO CSV > C:\SomeFolder\Task.csv
```

However When I submit the same lines using X command in SAS, it just runs and produce no output file or error in log. I am able to run other X commands successfully

```
 X "Tasklist /FO CSV > C:\SomeFolder\Task.csv";
```

I tried using `SYSTASK` as well but even that fails to create the csv file, am I missing something?

Comment: If you're reading the "C:\somefolder\task.csv" file into SAS afterwards try the filename pipe method: 

`filename x pipe "tasklist /fo csv";`

Then you can read the data into a data set using an infile statement:

`data tasks;`
`infile x; ...`

Comment: I will try this in the afternoon and let you know if it works. Thanks

Comment: I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work, it keeps showing datatstep is running but doesn't seems to output anything 

  FILENAME Tasklist PIPE 'TaskList';


  DATA Task;
  INFILE Tasklist;
  RUN;

Comment: Sorry I assumed that you'd know the '...' bit needed to contain `input` statements to read in the data.

The given answer below resolves your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the power of Printscreen and my reflex training playing Starcraft as a child, I managed to grab the error message.

> ERROR: Invalid argument/option: '>'

The issue is that X isn't really a command line; it's a single command interface.  You can't redirect output in quite the same way.

You have two options.  If you're just doing this for the purpose of reading this back into SAS, you should use a pipe to read it in.

```
filename tasks pipe "tasklist /FO CSV";
data mytasks;
infile tasks lrecl=1500 dlm=',' truncover dsd firstobs=2;
length image $50;
input
Image $
PID $
Session $
SessionNo $
MemUse $
;
run;
```

Otherwise, you can write a .bat file and execute that via `x`.

```
filename bat "c:\temp\task.bat";
data _null_;
file bat;
put "Tasklist /FO CSV > c:\temp\Task.csv";
run;
x "c:\temp\task.bat";
```

Comment: Running the original command with command/c option: X "command/c Tasklist /FO CSV > C:\SomeFolder\Task.csv"; seemed to work too - but in fact it produced an empty file. Your solution works great, thanks.